# Connect to Dynamics CRM in Windows Form Application using C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

In windows form application, I need to authenticate a user using C# and then let the user to perform CRUD operations on Case entity.

I tried following code snippet to authenticate but didn't worked. Any guidelines to do it work.

```
CrmConnection connection = CrmConnection.Parse("Url=" + org + "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc; Username=" + username + "; Password=" + password + ";");
            OrganizationService service = new OrganizationService(connection);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are pointing the URL to the Organization Web Service. I would suggest that this needs to be changed.

The following URL advises what the correct format is for the connection string, as the it will change depending if you are connecting to CRM Online or On-Premise and on versions.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695810(v=crm.6).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;

IOrganizationService organizationService = null;
string connectionString = string.Format(@"Url={Your url from IP:port/Organization}; Domain={Your Domain}; Username={User name}; Password={Password}");
Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmConnection connection = CrmConnection.Parse(connectionString);
organizationService = new Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationService(connection);
```